# Can not upload docs/pdf file using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an issue while uploading file using PHP. I can upload the image type file successfully but could not able to upload the pdf/docs type file. Here is my code:

```
$target_dir = "../../admin/enquiry/";
 $fileName = generateRandom() . '_' . $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($fileName);
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $uploadOk = 1;
 $check = getimagesize($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);
 header('Content-Type: application/json');  
 if ($check !== false) {  
       $result['msg'] = "check not false.";
            //  echo json_encode(array('status' => $check['mime']));
        $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {  
        $result['msg'] = "check false.";
            //  echo json_encode(array('status' => 'upload failed'));
        $uploadOk = 0;
   }

   if (file_exists($target_file)) {  
       echo json_encode(array('status' => 'file already exists'));
       $uploadOk = 0;
   }
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {  
        //
    } else {
              if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {  
                $result['msg'] = "File has uploaded successfully.";
                $result['num'] = 1;
                $result['img'] =$fileName;
              }else{
                $result['msg'] = "Sorry, Your File could not uploaded to the directory.";
                $result['num'] = 0;
              }

            }
```

I am getting message `check false.` means there is some problem with `getimagesize`. I can also passing the file size 138kb but in case of image its uploading successfully but other type file could not upload but I need to upload those.

Comment: Print your $_FILES and check if the file is actually uploaded or any other issue ? print_r($_FILES); exit;

Comment: @Ima: I have already printed and got that message there.

Comment: @RuhulAmin : Please check my comment on your post.I did as per you but same issue.

Comment: can you show you html code as well?

Comment: @satya, see my updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top of the file, add these code to enable php error.

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");


  $target_dir = "../../admin/enquiry/";
  if(isset($_FILES['attachment'])){
   $errors= array();
   $file_name =  generateRandom() . '_' .$_FILES['attachment']['name'];
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($file_name);
   $file_size = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
   $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
   $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['attachment']['name'])));

   $extension= array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf");

   if(in_array($file_ext,$extension)=== false){
       $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG,PNG or PDF file.";
   }

   if($file_size > 2097152) {
       $errors[]='File size must be exactely 2 MB';
   }

   if(empty($errors)==true) {
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$target_file);
       echo "Success";
   }else{
       print_r($errors);
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: @ Rahul : No,its not working. Its printing that message `check false` again.

Comment: what is the original error message you are getting, using `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");`

Answer (score 0):

Call getImagesize function conditionally.If file type is image then should it get call.

Comment: @ snehal : I need to allow all type file.

Answer (score 0):

do check the uploaded file is an image before calling getimagesize().

```
   if($file_type=="image/gif" || $file_type=="image/jpeg")
    {
       $check = getimagesize($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);
    }
```

also add condition `$check != NULL` in the `if-else` block

Answer (score 0):

Go to all PHP ini files and change the `post_max_size` to a high value .I also had the problem and I set it to 10000M

```
post_max_size=10000M
```